# How to join multiple rounded images one by one using line in css or css3

Tags: html, css

I have been created rounded images, using html and css3.

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="circular"></div>
```

css:

```
.circular {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    }
```

Now I want to join multiple images like these rounded images using a line, one-by-one, with some distance between the images.  How can I do that?

Comment: and u want want them horizontally right?

Comment: I want vertically @MohitBhasi.. i need above ten images..

Comment: check my answer out and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a line using css :after

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ojfvc4d6/1/)

```
.circular:after {
 background-color: red;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 48px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100px;
 width: 2px;
 left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content. You can try inserting text inside the quote to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple `div` of the class `.circular`.

Modified HTML:

```
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
<div class="circular"></div>
<hr>
```

You can also modify your css

```
.circular {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    }
hr{
    width: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left:50px; 
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Working example:http://jsfiddle.net/a4zh7yLd/3/

*Let me know if u r looking for something else :)*

Comment: @sona what line? can u explain ur question properly please

Comment: nhasi: thanks for your answer.. if i earned enough reputation., i will give you upvote..

Comment: @sona , sorry , ur question was not clear but i got an easier to understand answer for u (made one final update)